# Working CREATE VIEW gives syntax error inside IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple CREATE VIEW script for a statistics report that in itself works:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Report888View] AS
SELECT TOP 5000 pv.[AgentName] AS 'Label',
        COUNT(*) AS 'NumData1'
FROM [FullmaktsnodenProcess].[dbo].[ProcessingView] pv          
JOIN [Fullmaktsnoden].[dbo].[POAs] p ON (pv.FullmaktskollenPOAId=p.FullmaktskollenPoaId)
JOIN [Fullmaktsnoden].[dbo].[ReceivedPOAs] rp ON (p.Id=rp.Id)
WHERE pv.ErrorCode='888' and pv.Status <> 9
GROUP BY pv.[AgentName]
ORDER BY NumData1 DESC;
```

While I'm developing on SQL Server 2016 it's not guaranteed on customer installations, so I can't use CREATE OR ALTER.

So I thought I should put it inside a standard IF NOT EXISTS:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT [name]
    FROM sys.views
    WHERE [name] = 'Report888View'
)
BEGIN
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Report888View] AS
    SELECT TOP 5000 pv.[AgentName] AS 'Label',
            COUNT(*) AS 'NumData1'
    FROM [FullmaktsnodenProcess].[dbo].[ProcessingView] pv          
    JOIN [Fullmaktsnoden].[dbo].[POAs] p ON (pv.FullmaktskollenPOAId=p.FullmaktskollenPoaId)
    JOIN [Fullmaktsnoden].[dbo].[ReceivedPOAs] rp ON (p.Id=rp.Id)
    WHERE pv.ErrorCode='888' and pv.Status <> 9
    GROUP BY pv.[AgentName]
    ORDER BY NumData1 DESC;
END
```

(I've tried both with and without the BEGIN-END)

This code, however, give me "Incorrect syntax: 'CREATE VIEW' must be the only statement in the batch." I can't see what I'm doing wrong...

Edit: Corrected 'NumData1' --> NumData1

Comment: Not related to your question but your `ORDER BY 'NumData1'` is wrong. It is order by a string constant. Remove the single quote `NumData1`

Comment: If you're on 2016+, you could use `CREATE OR ALTER`.

Comment: @Larnu ,OP said `SQL Server 2016 it's not guaranteed on customer installations`

Comment: I'd missed that. Cheers @Squirrel

Comment: Thanks for the spotting of 'NumData1' - strangely the view always returned data in correct order despite the error :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should instead drop the view first if it exists and need to use a GO statement to separate the batch

```
if exists(select 1 from sys.views where name='Report888View' and type='v')
drop view Report888View;

go

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Report888View] AS
    SELECT TOP 5000 pv.[AgentName] AS 'Label',
            COUNT(*) AS 'NumData1'
    FROM [FullmaktsnodenProcess].[dbo].[ProcessingView] pv          
    JOIN [Fullmaktsnoden].[dbo].[POAs] p ON (pv.FullmaktskollenPOAId=p.FullmaktskollenPoaId)
    JOIN [Fullmaktsnoden].[dbo].[ReceivedPOAs] rp ON (p.Id=rp.Id)
    WHERE pv.ErrorCode='888' and pv.Status <> 9
    GROUP BY pv.[AgentName]
    ORDER BY 'NumData1' DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, while I would like to understand why my syntax isn't OK I'm pragmatic enough to switch to this, working, syntax :-)

Comment: Usually I don't like DROP/CREATE because of possible change of access rights but not a problem here.

Comment: @TommyPetersson the proper way is to use `IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Report888View') IS NOT NULL `

Comment: @PangiotisKanavos Would the IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Report888View') IS NOT NULL test still work if someone had been stupid enough creating a table called Report888View...? or would you need to add a type test here as well?

Answer (score 3):

You may try this

For SQL Server 2016+

```
    CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.Report888View AS
    SELECT TOP 5000 pv.[AgentName] AS 'Label',
            COUNT(*) AS 'NumData1'
    FROM [FullmaktsnodenProcess].[dbo].[ProcessingView] pv          
    JOIN [Fullmaktsnoden].[dbo].[POAs] p ON (pv.FullmaktskollenPOAId=p.FullmaktskollenPoaId)
    JOIN [Fullmaktsnoden].[dbo].[ReceivedPOAs] rp ON (p.Id=rp.Id)
    WHERE pv.ErrorCode='888' and pv.Status <> 9
    GROUP BY pv.[AgentName]
    ORDER BY NumData1 DESC;
```

For Below SQL Server 2016

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM SYS.VIEWS WHERE NAME = 'Report888View' )
BEGIN
     DROP VIEW dbo.Report888View        
END


---- OR YOU MAY USE THIS TO DROP VIEW

IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.Report888View') )  IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   DROP VIEW dbo.Report888View          
END

GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.Report888View AS
SELECT TOP 5000 pv.[AgentName] AS 'Label',
    COUNT(*) AS 'NumData1'
FROM [FullmaktsnodenProcess].[dbo].[ProcessingView] pv          
JOIN [Fullmaktsnoden].[dbo].[POAs] p ON (pv.FullmaktskollenPOAId=p.FullmaktskollenPoaId)
JOIN [Fullmaktsnoden].[dbo].[ReceivedPOAs] rp ON (p.Id=rp.Id)
WHERE pv.ErrorCode='888' and pv.Status <> 9
GROUP BY pv.[AgentName]
ORDER BY NumData1 DESC;
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, as it will work if the OP has recent version of SQL Server.

Comment: `(SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.Report888View') )` this will always return a row. So your IF statement is always false

Comment: Use `IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Report888View') IS NOT NULL` instead.

Comment: Possibly downvoted because of the "NOT" in IF NOT EXISTS - it shouldn't be there...

Comment: Sorry @DarkRob, too low reputation (new user) for being able to vote - you need to upvote my questions first... :-)

Answer (score 2):

If exist on the view, and you don't want these lsot 9so only create the view if it indeed doesn't exist) you would need to use a "dynamic" statement, such as the below:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT [name]
    FROM sys.views
    WHERE [name] = 'Report888View'
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
    SET @SQL = N'
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Report888View] AS
    SELECT TOP 5000 pv.[AgentName] AS ''Label'',
            COUNT(*) AS ''NumData1''
    FROM [FullmaktsnodenProcess].[dbo].[ProcessingView] pv          
    JOIN [Fullmaktsnoden].[dbo].[POAs] p ON (pv.FullmaktskollenPOAId=p.FullmaktskollenPoaId)
    JOIN [Fullmaktsnoden].[dbo].[ReceivedPOAs] rp ON (p.Id=rp.Id)
    WHERE pv.ErrorCode=''888'' and pv.Status <> 9
    GROUP BY pv.[AgentName]
    ORDER BY NumData1 DESC;';

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

END
```

The scope of the SQL run in by `sp_executesql` would be in a separate batch, and so not generate the error. Also note i "fix" the issue with your `ORDER BY`. `'NumData1` and `NumData1` are complete different; one is a **literal string** the other the alias of a column defined in the `SELECT`.

Alternatively, if you're looking to `CREATE` or `ALTER` the view, regardless of if it exists, you could use an expression to change the keyword's value:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = CASE WHEN  EXISTS(SELECT [name] FROM sys.views WHERE [name] = N'Report888View') THEN N'ALTER' ELSE N'CREATE' END + N' VIEW [dbo].[Report888View] AS
SELECT TOP 5000 pv.[AgentName] AS ''Label'',
        COUNT(*) AS ''NumData1''
FROM [FullmaktsnodenProcess].[dbo].[ProcessingView] pv          
JOIN [Fullmaktsnoden].[dbo].[POAs] p ON (pv.FullmaktskollenPOAId=p.FullmaktskollenPoaId)
JOIN [Fullmaktsnoden].[dbo].[ReceivedPOAs] rp ON (p.Id=rp.Id)
WHERE pv.ErrorCode=''888'' and pv.Status <> 9
GROUP BY pv.[AgentName]
ORDER BY NumData1 DESC;';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: You mean if the existing vew has specific permissions that the OP would want to retain? The way this is written doesn't explain why dropping the view would be a problem

Comment: Expanded for you @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Yeah, @Squirrel also spotted that 'NumData1' error :-), thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyView]'))
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyView]
AS
...
'
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of that after posting and the method could be used as a "stub" followed by an ALTER VIEW:

`IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.objects o where O.type = 'V ' AND name = 'Report888View')
BEGIN
 EXEC sp_executesql N'
 CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Report888View]
 AS 
 BEGIN 
  SELECT 1 AS Foo
 END
 '
END
GO

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[Report888View]
AS`
.
.
.
.